# Как задержать загрузку элемента сайта?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Есть [сайт](http://likebox.ru/queen/), при загрузке в меню джигурда. Дело в том, что пока рендерятся не стандартные шрифты, браузер фигачит стандартные, из-за этого все херится снизу на секунду -две. Заказчик негодует.

Есть ли способы задержать загрузку элемента на некоторое время?
Особенно будет видно, если нажать на "сообщество".

Comment: Вообще все шрифты аццтойно смотрятся :) у меня глаза устали через 20 секунд просмотра.

Comment: дизайн не мой, я программирую и мне пофигу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое поведение только в опере. В новой лисе, а также сафари и хроме не наблюдается. в IE вообще шрифтов я не увидел...

[Здесь вроде успешно борются](http://www.boxcarpress.com/us/blog/2009/11/05/css-font-face-flickering-in-firefox-somewhat-solved/).

Comment: хз, у меня огнелиса, данный болт имеется, в хроме тоже, хотя он не последний у меня.

Comment: ну я на своих браузерах проверил. результат таков. в других версиях может быть по-другому.

Comment: Ваша ссылка очень помогла, натолкнула на мысль. Сделал изначально элемент прозрачным, а когда страница загрузилась полностью, сделал элемент видимым. Код такой вот: 
<code>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#topnav").css('opacity', 1);
    });
    });
</script>
</code>

Словом, принимаю Ваш ответ, как решение, потому что Ваша ссылка оказалась очень полезной. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="over();">
<div id="df" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;visibility:visible"></div>
...Тут ваш код...    
<script>
function over(){
document.getElementById("df").style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: ps:Незабудте поставить галочку :)

Comment: Не совсем понял, при загрузке вызывается функция овер, где прописывается, что элемент невидимый. В нормальных браузерах, типа лисы, этот элемент не будет грузиться вообще, и когда я его сделаю видимым, вновь будет рендерится и увижу джигурду, разве нет?

Comment: вместо изменения visiblity надо менять opacity...

Comment: почему opacity я же скрываю этот div!?

Comment: Все верно, ваш вариант тоже работает, просто он скрывает страницу, речь шла про элемент - скрыть его пока он грузится.